# php post data with appended radio input

Tags: php, forms, post, append, submit

First of all sorry for my English and im not an expert of HTML, JS or PHP.

I appended some radio inputs to a div inside a form. 
The append process looks OK, but when i submit the form, i cant get the post data from the appended inputs.

```html
 <form method="POST" action="post.php">
        <div id="categradio">
        <input type='radio' name='catradio' value='opt1' id='cat1'></input><label for='cat1'>OPT1</label>
        <input type='radio' name='catradio' value='opt2' id='cat2'></input><label for='cat2'>OPT2</label>
        <input type='radio' name='catradio' value='opt3' id='cat3'></input><label for='cat3'>OPT3</label>
        </div>
    
        <div id="subcategradio"></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send"></input>
        </form>

        <script>
            function updateSubCats(currcat) {
         var data =  [{"0":"Analisi","Categoria":"Analisi","1":null,"Sottocategoria":null},{"0":"Creazione","Categoria":"Creazione","1":"Pagina Web","Sottocategoria":"Pagina Web"},{"0":"Creazione","Categoria":"Creazione","1":"Tabella","Sottocategoria":"Tabella"},{"0":"Creazione","Categoria":"Creazione","1":"Applicazione","Sottocategoria":"Applicazione"},{"0":"Creazione","Categoria":"Creazione","1":"Query","Sottocategoria":"Query"},{"0":"Creazione","Categoria":"Creazione","1":"Database","Sottocategoria":"Database"},{"0":"Monitoraggio","Categoria":"Monitoraggio","1":null,"Sottocategoria":null},{"0":"Importazione","Categoria":"Importazione","1":null,"Sottocategoria":null},{"0":"Calcolo","Categoria":"Calcolo","1":null,"Sottocategoria":null}];
         $('#subcategradio').empty();
         for (var i in data) {
          var cat = data[i][0];
          var subcat = data[i][1];
          if (cat == currcat && subcat != "" && subcat != null) {
           $('#subcategradio').append("<input type='radio' name='subcatradio' value='"+subcat+"' id='subcat"+i+"'></input><label  for='subcat"+i+"' class='nosel'>" + subcat + "</label>");
          }
         }
        }
        
        $('#categradio').change(function(){
        var cat = $('#categradio input[type=radio]:checked').val();
        updateSubCats(cat);
        });
        </script>
```

and the php file (post.php) to receive the post data:

```
<?php

$category = $_POST['catradio'];
$subcategory = $_POST['subcatradio'];

echo $category."<br>".$subcategory;

?>
```

Comment: is there any error you get ?

Comment: no, it just appears empty!

Comment: i just tried to add a static radio and if i select it, i get the value, but if i select the appended ones i get nothing.

Comment: try to use javascript for submitting the form, otherwise dynamically added radio button will not be posted. You can see this in the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem adding an invisible input.

```
<input name="subcategory" class="invisible" value="" id="empty"/>
```

when the appended radios selection change, the value of the invisible input change, and when i submit the form i get the value of the invisible input.

thanks to everyone